# System.nanotime giving negative numbers

Tags: android

I writing an android timer app that uses System.nanotime. The issue is that it's giving me underpredicted results as well negative numbers. redVal, blueVal, and greenVal are updated on each frame of the camera.

results

```
504455566
-95947265
9063721
61035
-99487305
-98937988
12664795
-75317382
```

code

```
        for (testAmount = 0; testAmount < 80; testAmount++) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lagSquare.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
                    lagStartTime = System.nanoTime(); //start lagTimer start
                }
            });
            while (redVal <= 100.0 && blueVal <= 100.0 && greenVal <= 100.0) {
                x=0;
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lagEndTime = System.nanoTime(); //start lagTimer end
                    lagSquare.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(000, 000, 000));//set lagSquare black
                }
            });
            lagTimeResult = (lagEndTime - lagStartTime);
            timeArray[testAmount] = lagTimeResult;
            Log.i("LTR", String.valueOf(lagTimeResult));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: From the documentation:
This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative).

Comment: Most likely you're using int where you should be using long to store the times and you get integer overflow.

Comment: I'd image it's either how your "lagStartTime" and "lagEndTime" are defined , or is it possible that the 2nd UI thread is completing before the first? Perhaps add a printout inside both threads to determine if that is the case?

Comment: @ChrisStillwell that makes no sense, the OP is printing a difference of 2 times, not wall clock time.

Comment: @ci_ What doesn't make sense? He is asking why he is getting negative numbers. The documentation says why it can be negative.

Comment: @ci_ Let's say startTime is -10 and endTime is -15. In his equation we have -15 - (-10) which gives -5.

Comment: But then endTime is earlier than startTime which is not the case, or the endTime is not the endTime which is entirely possible here, but it has nothing to do with nanotime and nothing to do with what it says in the docs.

Comment: @ci_ it does if you bounce between cores. Since nanotime is arbitrary each core can have a different value.

Comment: So what you're saying is on a multi core CPU nanotime should never be used because the values are arbitrary? Really? Come on.

Comment: No, I'm not saying you should or shouldn't use anything. I'm not here to argue the merits of nanotime. He asked why it wasn't working I gave a reason from the documentation.

Comment: what should i use to get a sub-millisecond timestamp?

Comment: @blue mage first of all you should show the declaration of the variables holding the time values.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to output a time difference which is relying upon values being set in different threads, without any synchronization. This will almost always end up with the wrong value:

```
for (testAmount = 0; testAmount < 80; testAmount++) {

            // this will schedule the Runnable to run *sometime* in
            // the future - but not necessarily right now
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lagStartTime = System.nanoTime(); //start lagTimer start
                }
            });

            // this will also schedule this Runnable to run *sometime* in
            // the future - but not necessarily after the first one
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lagEndTime = System.nanoTime(); //start lagTimer end
                }
            });

            // this will probably execute first (before either of
            // the other Runnables have completed)
            lagTimeResult = (lagEndTime - lagStartTime);
        }
```

You simply can't rely on the order of threads executing in the order you've coded them - and definitely not in a loop.
I can't understand from your question what you are trying to time, but the take-home rule is that whenever you have multiple threads, you can **never** rely on the order of execution without using some form of synchronization.

Comment: If they don't run in order, how would I synchronize them to make them run in order?

Comment: The easiest way to make them run sequentially and in order is to run them on a single thread. For more elaborate constructs, look into java.util.concurrent, particularly Executors (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Comment: I can not have them run on the same tread because the  `while loop` causes the app to crash,  and the async updates UI elements.